# How do you size a tkinter frame dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a frame I want to use as a sidebar navigation menu. I want the menu to be resize-able with the mouse. I have code that sizes the frame but it doesn't resize until you resize the toplevel window. I know about PanedWindows and that will not work for me.

```
from tkinter import *


def dragbar_on_click(event):
    event.widget.mouse_x = event.x


def dragbar_on_release(event):
    event.widget.mouse_x = 0


def dragbar_on_motion(event):
    if event.widget.mouse_x != 0:
        width = event.widget.parent.winfo_width() + event.x - event.widget.mouse_x

        event.widget.parent.config(width=width)


class DragBar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent


class SideMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.config(bg='red', width=300)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky='NSEW')
        self.grid_propagate(0)

        self.frame = Frame(self, bg='purple')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

        self.dragbar = DragBar(self, bg='green', width=10)
        self.dragbar.mouse_x = 0
        self.dragbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NSW')

        self.dragbar.bind("<Motion>", dragbar_on_motion)
        self.dragbar.bind("<Button-1>", dragbar_on_click)
        self.dragbar.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", dragbar_on_release)


root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

f = SideMenu(root)
Label(f.frame, text='This is a test line.').grid(sticky='NW')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a `PanedWindow`, is that correct?

Comment: I know about PanedWindows and that will not work for the current project I'm on. Thank you though for your suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand how what you're asking for is different. It seems like you want two widgets side-by-side with a movable barrier which can be used to make one side larger and the other smaller.

Comment: Yes but if I put the sidemenu in the left pane then the menu lives in the paned window. When I change windows I just hide the content pane and overlay a new one. This means I need to repopulate the menu for each frame. I have include another video showing the problem when using a pane to hold the sidemenu. I hope this will help you understand my problem better.... 
Video: https://youtu.be/RW7Fao4aZ70

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. I see one nav panel on the left. I don't see why you would have to duplicate it. You can have a left nav panel, and then a right panel that has whatever you want -- including other panels.  You can switch out the right without having to recreate anything on the left.

Comment: I want only one instance of sidemenu frame in the toplevel window at row=0, column=0, at row=0, column=1,  I put the content frame and that has a PanedWindow. When changing pages I only update row0, column=1, this leaves the sidemenu untouched. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say, my English is not the best.

Comment: What you are asking for can be done with a paned window. You can change what is on the right without changing what is on the left. The code in your question is nothing more but a re-implementation of a paned window. Why can't you use a paned window with exactly two panes: a nav panel and a "main" panel, and then when you change "pages", you simply change what is in "main"? The right "main" panel can itself have a paned window if you want.

Comment: As it is now I have to instantiate the sidemenu on each page and put it in the left pane, this means I have many copies of the sidemenu (1 for each page) and that's not any good because they all have their own state as the above video shows.

Comment: _"As it is now I have to instantiate the sidemenu on each page and put it in the left pane"_ - there's no technical reason for that. You may have designed it to be that way, but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: Let me think about my current implementation method and see if what you are saying will work in my situation, I'll let you know. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Yes I think you are right, I will need to refactor the code and paging system to make it work that way, thank you again.

Comment: Success Solved thanks to Bryan making me rethink my code structure.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNklD6EJjv0

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if there is a better way but it looks like the slider is updated when the `"<Configure>"` event fires.

So here is a quick hacky way to do this.

In your function `dragbar_on_motion` add these lines:

```
x = root.winfo_width()
y = root.winfo_height()
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(x, y))
```

This will force the `"<Configure>"` event to fire and will update the slider.

Here is your code modified:

```
from tkinter import *


def dragbar_on_click(event):
    event.widget.mouse_x = event.x


def dragbar_on_release(event):
    event.widget.mouse_x = 0

def dragbar_on_motion(event):
    if event.widget.mouse_x != 0:
        width = event.widget.parent.winfo_width() + event.x - event.widget.mouse_x
        event.widget.parent.config(width=width)
        x = root.winfo_width()
        y = root.winfo_height()
        root.geometry("{}x{}".format(x, y))

class DragBar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent


class SideMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.config(bg='red', width=300)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky='NSEW')
        self.grid_propagate(0)

        self.frame = Frame(self, bg='purple')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

        self.dragbar = DragBar(self, bg='green', width=10)
        self.dragbar.mouse_x = 0
        self.dragbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NSW')

        self.dragbar.bind("<Motion>", dragbar_on_motion)
        self.dragbar.bind("<Button-1>", dragbar_on_click)
        self.dragbar.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", dragbar_on_release)


root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

f = SideMenu(root)
Label(f.frame, text='This is a test line.').grid(sticky='NW')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean? For me this allows for resizing on the fly without having to moved the window.

Comment: I did like you said and added the code to dragbar_on_motion method and it did nothing.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work for me for some reason. I'm refactoring  my code so that I can use a PanedWindow, thank you for your help though Mike.

Comment: @DanielHuckson What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python Version 3.6